# How to read a url into a dataframe and join unwanted rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have the following code to import some data from a website, I want to convert my `data` variable into a dataframe.

I've tried with `pd.DataFrame`  and  `pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=";")` but always show me an error.

```
import requests
import io

# load file
data = requests.get('https://www.omie.es/sites/default/files/dados/AGNO_2020/MES_08/TXT/INT_PDBC_MARCA_TECNOL_1_01_08_2020_31_08_2020.TXT').content

# decode data
data = data.decode('latin-1')

# skip first 2 rows
data = data.split('\r\n')[2::]
del data[1]

# trying to fix csv structure
lines = []
lines_2 = []
for line in data:
  line = ';'.join(line.split(';'))
  if len(line) > 0 and line[0].isdigit():
    lines.append(line)
    lines_2.append(line)
  else:
    if len(lines) > 0:
      lines_2.append(lines_2[-1] + line)
      lines_2.remove(lines_2[-2])
    else:
      lines.append(line)


data = '\r\n'.join(lines_2)
print(data)
```

the expected ouput should be like this:

```
      date      1   2
0  29/08/2020  HI  RE ....
1  30/08/2020  HI  RE ....
2  31/08/2020  HI  RE ...
```

There are few rows that need to be added to the previos one (the main rows should be the rows who start by a date)

Answer (score 1):

Prayson's answer is correct, but the `skiprows` parameter should also be used (otherwise the metadata is interpreted as column names).

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(
 
 "https://www.omie.es/sites/default/files/dados/AGNO_2020/MES_08/TXT/INT_PDBC_MARCA_TECNOL_1_01_08_2020_31_08_2020.TXT",
  sep=";",
  skiprows=2,
  encoding='latin-1',
)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read text/csv data directly from URL with `pandas`

```py
import pandas as pd

URI = 'https://www.omie.es/sites/default/files/dados/AGNO_2020/MES_08/TXT/INT_PDBC_MARCA_TECNOL_1_01_08_2020_31_08_2020.TXT'
df = pd.read_csv(URI, sep=';', encoding='latin1')

print(df)
```

`pandas` will do the downloading for you. So no need for `requests` or `io.StringIO`.

Comment: try to run it and tell me the output... not work as you expected, ther are some lines in the txt that you need to fix...

Comment: The output is the TXT file as it is. You will need more data cleaning to get it to the clean format. Should I include that part too?

Comment: Thanks Prayson, probably is not the correct way to do it, but if I already have the data cleaned, why I need to do it again starting with the read_csv, is not other way possible? Please if you know how to clean all the data with your way, you are welcome to do it!

Comment: The correct way is the way you are comfortable with :) as it is your code. Can you explain the logic and I will try cleaning using `Pandas`.

Comment: when I try to read de data as a csv with ```df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=";")``` pandas show me this error: ```pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 25 fields in line 31, saw 48``` I asume that it is for the few ;;;;;;; in the last row... If you run my code, you could see the final ;;; that i think is the problem

Comment: Have try add `pass error_bad_lines=False` to your read csv?